# keeping maxInt in a variable (Standard ML)

Tags: sml, ml

How to put the maximum value of `Integer` into val in SML?
I saw that you can use `intMax`:

```
> Int.maxInt;
val it = SOME 1073741823 : int option
```

but If I'll try to put it as value into `val`, it will print error:

```
> val max:int = Int.maxInt;
Error: pattern and expression in val dec don't agree [tycon mismatch]
pattern:    int
expression:    int option
in declaration:
max : int = Int.maxInt
```

Although `val max = Int.maxInt` works, it makes:`val max = SOME 1073741823 : int option`.

I would like the variable to be of `int` type and not of `int option`.

In other words, the output should be:

```
> val max = 1073741823 : int
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to put value bigger than maxInt?
I would like to calculate:

```
fun someCalculation num = ceil((Math.sqrt(1.0+8.0*real(num))-1.0)/2.0);
val max_int = Option.valOf Int.maxInt;
val current = someCalculation max_value;
```

because of `8.0*real(maxInt)` it won't work. Is is possible to calculate? Notice that the final answer isn't bigger than maxInt.

Comment: If your question was about something else, please ask a new question and think about what you want to ask so you don't have to change it all the time. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> How to put the maximum value of Integer into val in SML?

You can remove the "option" part using `Option.valOf : 'a option -> 'a`:

```
- val max = valOf Int.maxInt;
> val max = 1073741823 : int
```

Using `valOf` is generally not safe, since `valOf NONE` raises an exception:

```
- valOf NONE;
! Uncaught exception:
! Option
```

This would only happen if a future version of your compiler would ship with an arbitrary-size `Int` module. Since SML/NJ already has [`IntInf`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/int-inf.html) as a separate module, that's probably not going to happen right away.

> Is it possible to put value bigger than maxInt?

Not using an *int* (too small):

```
- valOf Int.maxInt + 1;
! Uncaught exception:
! Overflow
```

And not using a *real* (too imprecise):

```
- Real.== (real (valOf Int.maxInt) + 1.0,
           real (valOf Int.maxInt));
> val it = true : bool
```

But using the `IntInf` library, yes:

```
- IntInf.maxInt;
> val it = NONE : int option

- IntInf.fromInt (valOf Int.maxInt) * 8;
> val it = 8589934584 : IntInf.int
```

As you can see, SML/NJ overloads integer literals so they work both as *int* (read: *Int31.int*) and as *IntInf.int*.